# Memory consumption of BigDecimal (Java)

Tags: java, floating-point, double, bigdecimal

I'm considering writing a small java class for handling decimals. The basic idea would be to have two `int` fields, one for holding the value to the left of the decimal point, and the other would hold the value to the right of the decimal. E.g in the following number:

`100.50`

100 would be in the first int, and 50 would be in the 2nd.

Is that worth doing, or does `BigDecimal` already do something like this in its implementation?

Comment: Let's turn the question around; do you have any particular reason why you'd like to avoid using BigDecimal?

Comment: I'm wondering, is this question fit for [SO]? Doesn't seem to have any other answer than "it depends"

Comment: @ClickUpvote What would be the content of the second integer (the one for the fragment) in this case: `1.00000001`?

Comment: There may be reasons to avoid using BigDecimal, but none are apparent in your question.  Note: in Java 7, BigDecimal uses a `long` for the unscaled value when it can, which uses the same memory as two `int` values.  If you are really worried about memory consumption use a `double` or a scaled `long` but you have to be sure you need to do this.

Comment: One potential problem with your model is: how do you propose to represent the following two numbers with your present data model: "100.50" and "100.005"?

Comment: @scottb I think my question was the same... Looking at OPs previous questions, (as OP is obviously highly skilled, and quite knowledgeable) this rather looks to be an exploitation of [SO], and a part of a clever sociological strategy to gain unlimited reps: 1. post huge number of questions 2. choose a clever name, with a subliminal message 3. reps 4. ??? 5. profit!

Comment: @ppeterka66 You're considering stackoverflow points way more important than they are.... I just post the questions that I come across / think of during my daily work, and other people who find them useful happen to upvote them. I like the idea of my username being a subliminal messages, though. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good rule of thumbs is (paraphrased from J. Bloch, Effective Java, 2nd Ed.):

"Never reinvent the wheel.  If there is a Java API class that can be used to do what you want, then use it rather than trying to rewrite your own class.  Language developers have been working for years to refine and optimize the libraries, often in ways that would be impractical for independent developers (and continue to optimize them)."

It may be that your needs are simple. For example, perhaps you'll just be using this number to identify an object (like the Dewey Decimal System) and you'll never be doing numeric operations on them.  If your needs are this simple (you haven't told us what you'll be doing with these numbers), then it may be sensible to write your own class as an optimization.

However, if you're going to be doing any kind of math on these numbers, then using BigDecimal to represent a numeric quantity with fixed precision is absolutely the right way to go.  I wouldn't even worry about the memory.  Memory is cheap.

Consider also that BigDecimals already:

- are immutable
- are a subclass of Number
- implement the Comparable interface
- provides operations for arithmetic, scale manipulation, rounding, comparison, hashing, and format conversion.